# While grouping two columns into a new dataframe , how do I create another column in the new dataframe labeling where each value came from? See example

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently using the following code to combine Col A and Col B to get Col A & B in DataFrame B below:

```
out = (df
   .groupby('Col A', group_keys=False, sort=False)
   .apply(lambda d: d.iloc[:, ::-1].unstack().drop_duplicates())
   .reset_index(drop=True).to_frame(name='Col A&B')
)
```

My question is: how can I create the Col C in DataFrame B that uses the column headers from DataFrame A to label where each value in Col A & B came from?

DataFrame A

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | 10 |
| 1000 | 100 | 20 |
| 2000 | 200 | 30 |
| 2000 | 200 | 40 |

DataFrame B

| Col A & B | Col C |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Col C |
| 20 | Col C |
| 100 | Col B |
| 1000 | Col A |
| 30 | Col C |
| 40 | Col C |
| 200 | Col B |
| 2000 | Col A |

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `stack` + `drop_duplicates` instead of `groupby`:

```
df.stack().reset_index(level=1).drop_duplicates().rename(columns={0: 'Col A & B', 'level_1': 'Col C'})

   Col C  Col A & B
0  Col A        100
0  Col B         10
1  Col B         20
2  Col A        200
2  Col B         30
3  Col B         40
```

Comment: thanks the problem is I need to retain the order as shown in the example.

Comment: You can try something like this (reorder col B & A before stack): `df[['Col B', 'Col A']].stack().reset_index(level=1).drop_duplicates(keep='last').rename(columns={0: 'Col A & B', 'level_1': 'Col C'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) in each group.

```
df_new = df.groupby('Col A'
                   ).apply(lambda g : g.stack().reset_index().sort_values([0],
                                                                          ascending=True)
                          ).reset_index(drop=True
                                       ).drop('level_0', 
                                              axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'Col A & B', 
                                                                      'level_1': 'Col C'}
                                                            ).drop_duplicates(subset=['Col C', 
                                                                                      'Col A & B'])

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
    Col C  Col A & B
0   Col C         10
1   Col C         20
2   Col B        100
4   Col A       1000
6   Col C         30
7   Col C         40
8   Col B        200
10  Col A       2000
```

Comment: Please see updated table. I think this is perfect if i can just do it for 3 columns instead of 2.

Comment: @JohnMarkJohnson, See the updated ;)